# React embed tag play video cannot fullscreen

Tags: reactjs, video, embed

My code:

```
<embed style={{ width: '600px', height: '380px' }}
       wmode="transparent"
       allowFullScreen='true'
       src={this.state.play ? vSrc : ''}
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

React code uses `<embed>` tag to play video. The video can play, but cannot be shown fullscreen.
How can I resolve the problem?
ps: I tried and found the bug is attribute `allowfullscreen` novalue. When React renders the DOM, `allowfullscreen`'s value is ignored. I can't set it in the render() DOM.

Comment: I had found a solution to fix the question.-.-